# I simply want to reformat a 2TB Seagate for use in Ubuntu with full permissions

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, format

I have completely backed up all data from said drive and physically disconnected the backup drive so I don't screw it up.  I've searched high and low for the basic command line syntax and proper format to no avail. Can somebody give me the proper format and the Terminal command to perform this operation (and how to make sure I'm not formatting my C: drive)?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. It's for addtl storage

Comment: In all honesty, I've read the answers referring to these but they are either incomplete or I simply don't fully understand them and don't want to destroy anything. Plus permissions

Comment: I will get to work on that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing some deleted comments, but why are you not just running `fdisk -l` to determine which one is the seagate drive (it prints enough info to determine this, unless all drives are 2tb seagate. and then runnging `mkfs.ext4 /path/to/drive`?

Comment: because I didn't know how to do that prior to your answer. i didn't find that command. i will do that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple, first determine which is the drive you want to format I personally like to use `fdisk` an example output from my machine

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLV256HCHP-00000              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 26126327-1D94-4446-BF34-06CA24DCBF84

Device            Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2  1050624  17827839  16777216    8G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p3 17827840 500118158 482290319  230G Linux filesystem
```

I only have one drive on my current machine, but you can see it outputs the capacity and vendor amongst other useful information for determining which is the target drive.

Then if it is un-partitioned partition it (again I used fdisk in the past but for this machine I had to use gdisk for the boot partition but the commands are the same)

```
fdisk /path/to/drive #(in my case it would be /dev/nvme0n1
# from here on out everything in fdisk will be prepended with a '#'

# o 
# n 
# <press enter>
# <press enter>
# <press enter>
# at this point your drive should have a single partition in it though I may have missed an enter
# w
```

Now that we've partitioned the drive you just need to create a filesystem which was done in the comments

```
mkfs.ext4 /path/to/partition # note that it will be something like /dev/sda1
```

Note again that we gave `mkfs` the path to a partition and not the actual drive itself